# How to remove everything after a ',' in a Column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a column containing an address.
I want to remove everything after the `,` in the string.
How do I go about doing that in PostgreSQL?

I've tried using `REPLACE`, but that only works on specific strings, which is a problem because each row in the column would have a different address.

```
SELECT *
FROM address_book

r_name r_address

xxx    123 XYZ st., City, Zipcode
yyy    333 abc road, City, Zipcode
zzz    222 qwe blvd, City, Zipcode
```

I'm need column `r_address` to only return:

```
123 XYZ st.
333 abc road
222 qwe blvs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `split_part` function, like so:

```
SELECT r_name, split_part(r_address, ',', 1) AS street
FROM address_book
```

Docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/51afe/1